# How to get row and column length of a 2-dimensional array in rails 3?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array

can somebody tell how to get the row and column length of a 2-dimensional array in rails 3?

My array goes like this:

```
 payroll = Array.new[Payroll.count][2]
```

When we are getting the length of a 1-dimensional array we do like

```
 array.length
```

How about in a 2-dimensional array?

Im thinking of doing something like:

```
 payroll = Array.new[Payroll.count][2]

 for i in 0..payroll.row.length - 1
  for j in 0..1
   puts payroll[i][j]
  end
 end
```

I just wanna know the right way. Pls help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A two dimensional array is just an array of arrays, so just use `payroll.length` to get the height and `payroll[0].length` to get the width (assuming all rows are the same width). Here's what your loop looks like using that idea:

```
for i in 0..payroll.length - 1
  for j in 0..payroll[i].length - 1
    puts payroll[i][j]
  end
end
```

But an easier way to loop through an array is using an iterator method. Here I'll change the `for` loops to `each.with_index` (use `each_with_index` if your Ruby doesn't support `each.with_index`):

```
payroll.each.with_index do |row, i|
  row.each.with_index do |cell, j|
    puts payroll[i][j]
  end
end
```

And now I'll make it even simpler since I'm assuming you don't really need access to the indexes at all, just the individual elements in the array:

```
payroll.each do |row|
  row.each do |cell|
    puts cell
  end
end
```